# Mobile website changing to desktop when rotating to landscape mode

Tags: html, css

I am using `@media screen and (max-width:768px)` to change the view of my website on mobile but when I rotate to landscape mode it changes to desktop website meaning it shows content which was hidden using
`@media screen and (max-width:768px)`. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. If your media query applies up to 768px, and a landscape phone is larger than that, this behavior is expected, right? Change your media query or change your expectations.

Comment: You can also use [`orientation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/orientation). Perhaps something like `@media (min-width:768px) and (orientation:portrait), (min-height:768px) and (orientation:landscape) { ... }`?

Comment: @OskarGrosser Should i write the code for desktop or mobile under this media query

Comment: @yashthe It's just an example how such a media-rule could look like, you should use one that fits your needs best. It's generally better to make a website mobile-first, meaning designing the mobile-version first, and then (using media-rules) changing the layout for greater screen-sizes. This would mean to use `max-*` instead of `min-*` as I have written before. Sorry if that's confusing!

Answer (score 1):

What `@media screen and (max-width:768px){ ... }` does is it will only apply everything in that block if the device the user has has a screen of a width of 768px or lower (taking into consideration double pixel density etc, but that a whole other can of worms)

So when you turn your phone sideways it's height becomes it's width and since that is more than `768px`, it does not apply your "mobile layout".

One option would be to increase `768px` to a bigger number, or even split some of the rules for smaller and higher widths, like for example having rules for `max-width: 640px` and for `max-width: 960px`

Comment: I tried doing what you said but it still does the same. I even set the max width to 100px but it still does the same

Comment: Check your screen size and whether there are other conflicting rules. Remember you can always check your mobile layout from any desktop browser as well, provided you just resize the window or use their "responsive view", so you can use the desktop web inspector